# Accessing an included object

Tags: json, node.js, loopbackjs

I have the following JSON Object, which is the result of a `loopback` model (Classifications), with a relationship with another model (Labels).

My call to get the classifications is:

```
modClassification.findOne({ 
             where: { id: classificationid }, 
             include: 'labels' }, 
             function( err, classification ){ ...
```

And this returns classification with something like

```
{ id: 'b01',
  title: 'population',
  country_id: 1,
  labels: 
   [ { column_id: 'b1',
       classification_id: 'b01',
       classification_title: 'population',
       dsporder: 1,
       label: 'Total_Persons_Males',
       country_id: 1,
       id: 1 },
     { column_id: 'b2',
       classification_id: 'b01',
       classification_title: 'population',
       dsporder: 2,
       label: 'Total_Persons_Females',
       country_id: 1,
       id: 2 } ] }
```

which is what I would expect.

I now need to loop over the labels and access it's properties, but this is where I am stuck.

```
classification.labels[0] = undefined..
```

I have tried looping, each and whatever I can find online, but can't seem to get to each labels properties.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong/need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are including related models inside a `findOne` call, you need to JSONify the result before accessing the related records:

```
classification = classification.toJSON()
```

Then you should be able to access the included label items as you expect.

See https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter, specifically the "Access included objects" section.

Note this does not work the same when you retrieve more than one result in an array. In that case you'll need to perform `toJSON()` on each item in the array.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing!  Thanks Brian!